# Grep the email addresses with TLD from a file

Tags: bash, shell, email, web, sh

I've a file with email addresses as follows:

```
example.example@gmail.com
Jhon.sam@example.com
George.callaghan@example.co.uk
Example@example.org
kelly.diana@organization.ac.in
```

I need the output with only TLD domains in bash script.

The output should be:

```
example.example@gmail.com
Jhon.sam@example.com
Example@example.org
```

The grep command I used is

```
grep -i -o '[A-Z0-9._%+-]\+@[A-Z0-9.-]\+\.[A-Z]\{2,4\}' webpage.html
```

Answer (score 0):

you are almost there! just remove the `.` from `[A-Z0-9.-]` and add `$` at the end:

```
$ grep -i -o '[A-Z0-9._%+-]\+@[A-Z0-9-]\+\.[A-Z]\{2,4\}$' emails
example.example@gmail.com
Jhon.sam@example.com
Example@example.org
$
```

Comment: email_filtered="$(grep -i -o '[A-Z0-9._%+-]\+@[A-Z0-9-]\+\.[A-Z]\{2,4\}$' webpage.html)"
echo "$email_filtered"

I tried this way, but I get no data from the webpage.html. This file has emails in the form of text. Please help me

Comment: @samhithgardas what does `webpage.html` contain? if format is different from the one posted in the question (i.e. one address per line), this solution won't work. please show exact content of `webpage.html`.